Optimising three variable to achieve a result
In the following, I want to adjust the values of a,b,c subjected to the condition  a^2=bc such that $R43=rank(augA4)-rank(augA3)=4$ and $R32$, $R21$ and $R10$ are all less than 4.
(*Assumptions*)        
$Assumptions = a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0
(*Identity matrix*)
I4 = IdentityMatrix[4];

(*Given set of matrices*) 
A0 = MatrixForm[-{{0, a, b, 0}, {a, 0, 0, -c}, {-b, 0, 0, g}, 
         {0, c, a, 0}}]; A1 = IdentityMatrix[4]; A2 = 0*I4;  A3 = 0*I4;

(*Augmented matrices formed by arranging the above matrices*) 
    augA0 = A0; 
    augA1 = ArrayFlatten[{{A0, 0}, {A1, A0}}]; 
    augA2 = ArrayFlatten[{{A0, 0, 0}, {A1, A0, 0}, {0, A1, A0}}]; 
    augA3 = ArrayFlatten[{{A0, 0, 0, 0}, {A2, A1, A0, 0}, 
         {0, A2, A1, A0}}]; 
    augA4 = ArrayFlatten[{{A0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {A3, A2, A1, A0, 0}, 
         {0, A3, A2, A1, A0}}]; 
    MatrixRank[augA4]
    MatrixRank[augA3]
    MatrixRank[augA2]
    MatrixRank[augA1]
    MatrixRank[augA0]

How can one find such ,  and  such that R43=4, and R32, R21,R10 are all less than 4?

Ummm.... so what's the problem?

Ah, so the probem is that I do not know how to achieve this! I mean how to find $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that R43=4, and R32, R21,R10 are all less than 4.

@Bill, thanks. I want to difference of rank to be 4. Specifically, I want to find whether there exist $a,b,c$ with $a^2=bc$ such that $rank(augA4) - rank(augA3) = 4$, and at the same time, the other three differences $rank(augA3) - rank(augA2)$, $rank(augA2) - rank(augA1)$ and $rank(augA1) - rank(augA0)$ are all less than 4.

I apologize for my mistakes. If I haven't made any more mistakes then MatrixRank[augA4]-MatrixRank[augA3]==0 and you want that =4, MatrixRank[augA2]-MatrixRank[augA1]==4 and you want that <4, MatrixRank[augA1]-MatrixRank[augA0]==4 and you want that <4. All those are independent of the values of a,b,c

And change A0=MatrixForm[-{{0, a, b, 0}...] to A0=-{{0, a, b, 0}... because MatrixForm makes something pretty to look at but the result cannot be used for further calculations. Beginners make that mistake again and again and Wolfram won't put in an error message warning people to not do this.

Thanks a lot @Bill. Now, instead of focusing on a,b, and c (thanks to your observation), can I changes A1 to something else (instead of identity matrix), in order to achieve what I want?

"Just changing A1" has a lot of degrees of freedom, maybe too many to answer. Can you look at the ranks of your 6 matricies and see any pattern or any hint about the simplest change to get where you want to go?

The minimum of MatrixRank for augA3 I can achieve with a==b==c==0 is 9. And the max. of MatrixRang for augA4 is 12. Therefore the max. difference is 3 and not 4 as requested.

Thanks @DanielHuber. I am convinced that changing A1 would allow me to achieve the goal. But I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I ask this as a separate question?

Only changing A1 would  change nothing in relation to A3 and A4.

@Bill, just noted that rank(augA0) is sensitive to the the choice of non-zero a,b,c. For example, rank(augA0)=4 for a=b=c=1, and rank(augA0)=2 for a=b=1, c=2.

You should eliminate MatrixForm from the definition of A0. ArrayFlatten does not recognize MatrixForm[] as an array. It is regarded as a single matrix element.
